# Swift map from array of objects to array of async functions and await them all

Tags: swift, async-await

I've just updated to Xcode 13.2.1 and now have access to async await and I'm trying to find places I can "convert" from Combine over to async await.

I want to achieve the following...

Given a type like...

```
struct Person {
  let name: String

  func fetchAvatar(completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> Void) {
    // fetch the image from the web and pass it into the completion.
  }
}
```

I currently have a function like this...

```
func fetchAllTheAvatars(people: [Person], completion: ([UIImage]) -> Void) {
  Publisher.MergeMany(
    people.map { person in
      Future<UIImage?, Never> { promise in
        person.fetchAvatar { promise(.success($0)) }
      }
    }
  )
  .compactMap { $0 }
  .collect()
  .sink { completion($0) }
  .store(in: &cancellables )
}
```

Now... it looks to me like this could be a good candidate for moving to using async await and `AsyncSequence` maybe...?!? It doesn't have to be ideal though, I just want to get a feel of how to use them. I'm used to `async await` in JS and TS and this just seems a little bit different. :D

I added a wrapper function to my Person...

```
func fetchAvatar() async -> UIImage? {
  await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
    fetchAvatar { image in
      continuation.resume(returning: image)
    }
  }
}
```

But now I'm stuck on how to update my `fetchAllTheAvatars` function.

```
func fetchAllTheAvatars(people: [Person]) async -> [UIImage] {
  people.map { ...???... }
}
```

Everywhere I have seen online seems to use `for await line in url.lines { ... }` but I don't yet have an AsyncSequence. I need to somehow "convert" my non-async array of `Person` into an `AsyncSequence` of `() -> Image?`.

Is that possible? Am I going about this entirely the wrong way?

Thanks

Comment: Your combine code doesn't necessarily fetch the images in the same order as the `people` array. Is that intentional?

Comment: I'm sure you've seen the [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10058) but it looks like you can just `yield` in the `sink` of the method you already have.

Comment: John Sundell wrote a bunch of [helpful articles](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/tags/concurrency/) about Swift Concurrency among others also to migrate existing APIs to async/await.

Comment: @Sweeper ah, I didn’t know that but in the actual code the order of the data doesn’t matter. Thanks though, I’ll keep that in mind in the future. 

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The standard pattern is `TaskGroup`. Add your tasks for the individual images, and then `await` in a `for` loop, `map`, or, in this case, `reduce`:

```swift
func fetchAllTheAvatars(people: [Person]) async -> [Person.ID: UIImage] {
    await withTaskGroup(of: (Person.ID, UIImage?).self) { group in
        for person in people {
            group.addTask { await (person.id, person.fetchAvatar()) }
        }
        
        return await group.reduce(into: [:]) { dictionary, result in 
            if let image = result.1 {
                dictionary[result.0] = image
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note, because the order is not guaranteed and because some of your `Person` may not return an image, my implementation returns an efficient, order-independent, structure (i.e., a dictionary).

Needless to say, the above assumes that you make `Person` conform to `Identifiable`:

```swift
struct Person: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    
    func fetchAvatar() async -> UIImage? { … }
}
```